# Can't connect to WAN or Internet via wireless repeater running OpenWRT

Tags: networking, firewall, openwrt

I've set up what was previously my primary router as a wireless repeater using the [OpenWRT relay configuration guide](http://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration). It now connects to a new ISP provided router which is connected to the Internet.

There's one problem: devices that are connected to the repeater (both wired *and* wireless) cannot get a response back from the Internet. Trying to make a connection to the Internet seems to result in never-ending loading spinners. I also cannot connect to my new primary router from these devices.

However, I have SSH'd into the router and managed to successfully make a cURL HEAD request to an Internet address. I can also download and install packages on the router (using opkg and LuCI) from the Internet successfully. I can also connect to my primary router from the repeater. All this makes me suspect that my firewall configuration is wrong, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to firewalls. I've attached a screenshot of my firewall configuration below and would appreciate if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Additionally, as it used to be my primary router, it was previously configured with a 2.4GHz Guest WiFi network in addition to non-Guest 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks which was done by following one of the OpenWRT guides. I *think* (I did it years ago) I set up a second VLAN in order to set up the Guest network and I'm not sure if that's what could be causing my issue.

[image: 2]]

Comment: If you are not sure what you did, why don't you reset the router and restart from scratch?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, but it looks like I'm going to have to do that after all.

Comment: There are too many possibilities, maybe why there were no answers.

Comment: you haven't provided enough information for an adequate answer. basic topology with IP's would help. it sounds like you may still have VLAN routing setup in the router. disable it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I managed to fix my issue by downgrading to OpenWRT 15.05.1 after coming across various posts on the OpenWRT/LEDE forum by users complaining that relayd wasn't working on OpenWRT 17.x.